# Check if a Hibernate PersistentBag is loaded?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class that has a collection being fetched automatically, but in a lazy fashion, since it's not always needed. I have a method that relies on that that collection, but I want it to not trigger the lazy-loading if it hasn't fired already. Is there a way to tell if a `PersistentBag` has not been loaded, without triggering that load?

Example class:

```
class MyClass {
  private List<MyThings> toybox;

  @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "toyBox")
  public List<MyThings> getToybox () {
    return toybox;
  }

  public void setToybox (List<MyThings> toybox) {
    this.toybox = toybox;
  }

  @Transient
  public List<String> toyNames() {
    if (hasNotAlreadyLoaded(this.toybox) {
      return null; // Can't run right now; data not available
    }
    return parseToybox(this.toybox);
  }
}
```

So, the question is what should `boolean hasNotAlreadyLoaded(PersistantBag bag)` do to check if the bag has been loaded? Checking the `.size()` I tried, but that triggers the load...

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Hibernate API (Not pure JPA) you can use the method [Hibernate.isInitialized(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized(java.lang.Object))

From the Javadoc, it returns

> true if the argument is already initialized, or is not a proxy or collection

Answer (score 1):

If you use JPA2 you can do it using `PersistenceUnitUtil` as below

```
PersistenceUnitUtil unitUtil = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();

Assert.assertTrue(unitUtil.isLoaded(myclassInstance));

Assert.assertFalse(unitUtil.isLoaded(myclassInstance, "toyBox"));
```